# How to open server display configuration in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I want to open  'server display configuration' in  ubuntu.

I tried this System Tools -> Administration  -> NVidia X server settings

but I get this as shown in the picture.

My goal is to have both of my 2 screens active -  I only have 1 of them active while the other one is black screen.

[image]

I go in System -> Preferences-> Displays
In Display there is no 'Detect Monitor'. I get this.

[image]

I have my 2 screen connected to my computer as shown below. The 2 black sticks connected to the computer.

[image]

Comment: Tried using 'sudo nvidia-xconfig' , then reboot or restart your display manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am little unclear about your question but as you write "My goal is to have both of my 2 screens active - I only have 1 of them active while the other one is black screen" try below solution.

Click on `System -> Preferences -> Display`, which will display "Display Preference" window.

If you see only one monitor, click on Detect Monitor, which should detect all the monitors connected to the Ubuntu laptop or desktop.

Uncheck Mirror Screens. When you have this enabled, both the monitors will show the same display, which you don’t want.

Highlight the first monitor and click the `On` button. The first monitor will already be in on state.

Highlight the second monitor and click the `On` button.

To change the display order of the monitors, simply drag the monitor to re-arrange them accordingly.

Comment: In Display there is no 'Detect Monitor'. I added a picture above.

Comment: look at bottom left site, there is button `Detect Displays`...

Comment: But nothing happens when I press on it.

Comment: how did you connect second display?? is there one more port in motherboard or graphic card (if yes then which), or through USB...

Comment: I have 2 black stick as shown in the picture above.